# Redirection by clicking calendar event notification

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am adding an event to the calendar in Android and setting the reminder as 1 hour before. I am receiving the event reminder. Now i want to open my app on clicking the event reminder notification. Is this possible in android?. If possible how can i do this. if not possible any other suggestion for achieving this feature.

Comment: It'll be much simpler to send the event notification from your app itself

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya I need to add an event in the calendar from my app and when the user click calendar reminder i need to take the user to my app. How can i achieve this by sending event notification. I don't want the app to handle the event reminder. That's why i am creating an event in calendar so that the calendar will remind the user about the event at given time.